# XML same node but different id read method required

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, xml-parsing

I need a simple node parsing technique. I have already read by node.attribute and node.innertext. Please help, if you know Visual Studio C#.net.

This is my code:

```
<abc>
    <Limits>
        <Row>
            <LimitId>101</LimitId>
            <Max>10000</Max>
            <Current>0</Current>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LimitId>102</LimitId>
            <Max>6000</Max>
            <Current>0</Current>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LimitId>109</LimitId>
            <Max>25000</Max>
            <Current>0</Current>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LimitId>200</LimitId>
            <Max>45000</Max>
            <Current>0</Current>
        </Row>
    </Limits>
</abc>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried, as follow: foreach (XmlNode node in doc.GetElementsByTagName("LimitId"))
AcctNo = node.InnerText.Substring(0, node.InnerText.Length);

Comment: Another method is: foreach (XmlNode node in doc.GetElementsByTagName("Response"))
                {
                    string LogonId = node.Attributes["Challengekey"].Value;
                    string XId = node.Attributes["XId"].Value;
                }

Comment: I want LimitId by Max and Current value of selected LimitId

Comment: Please *[edit]* your question to show your code (after pasting it in, highlight is and hit the `{}` button). Code is unreadable in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This little example does the following:

1. deserializes the xml string into instance of a typed object (LimitCollection)
2. Demonstrates iterating over all the limits outputting it's values to the console
3. Finding a particular Limit record using it's id via LINQ method FirstOrDefault

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.IO;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using System.Xml.Serialization;

   namespace ConsoleApplication11
   {
       class Program
       {
           static void Main(string[] args)
           {
               string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
               <abc>
                  <Limits>
                       <Row>
                           <LimitId>101</LimitId>
                           <Max>10000</Max>
                           <Current>0</Current>
                       </Row>
                       <Row>
                           <LimitId>102</LimitId>
                           <Max>6000</Max>
                           <Current>0</Current>
                       </Row>
                       <Row>
                           <LimitId>109</LimitId>
                           <Max>25000</Max>
                           <Current>0</Current>
                       </Row>
                       <Row>
                           <LimitId>200</LimitId>
                           <Max>45000</Max>
                           <Current>0</Current>
                       </Row>
                   </Limits>
               </abc>";

               XmlSerializer d = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LimitCollection));
               LimitCollection deserializedXml = (LimitCollection)d.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));

               Console.WriteLine("Iterating all limits:");
               foreach (Limit lim in deserializedXml.Limits)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine($"LimitId: {lim.LimitId}, Current: {lim.Current}, Max: {lim.Max}");
               }

               Console.WriteLine();
               Limit particularLimit = deserializedXml.Limits.FirstOrDefault(l => l.LimitId == 109);
               if (particularLimit != null)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine($"Particular limit: {particularLimit.LimitId}, Current: {particularLimit.Current}, Max: {particularLimit.Max}");
               }

               Console.WriteLine("Press any key to finish...");
               Console.ReadKey();
           }
       }


       [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
       [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false, ElementName = "abc")]
       public partial class LimitCollection
       {

           private Limit[] limitsField;

           /// <remarks/>
           [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Row", IsNullable = false)]
           public Limit[] Limits
           {
               get
               {
                   return this.limitsField;
               }
               set
               {
                   this.limitsField = value;
               }
           }
       }

       /// <remarks/>
       [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
       public partial class Limit
       {

           private byte limitIdField;

           private ushort maxField;

           private byte currentField;

           /// <remarks/>
           public byte LimitId
           {
               get
               {
                   return this.limitIdField;
               }
               set
               {
                   this.limitIdField = value;
               }
           }

           /// <remarks/>
           public ushort Max
           {
               get
               {
                   return this.maxField;
               }
               set
               {
                   this.maxField = value;
               }
           }

           /// <remarks/>
           public byte Current
           {
               get
               {
                   return this.currentField;
               }
               set
               {
                   this.currentField = value;
               }
           }
       }

   }
   ```

When you have namespaces in your production xml, as you updated in the comments, you can use the same approach slighly modified in my another example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env=""w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"" xmlns:m0=""schemas/type.xsd"" xmlns:m1=""schemas/app.xsd"">
    <env:Body>
        <m1:GetLimitsRes > 
            <m1:Response Response=""1""> 
                <m0:Limits> 
                    <m0:Row> 
                        <m0:LimitId>100</m0:LimitId> 
                        <m0:Max>10000</m0:Max> 
                        <m0:Current>0</m0:Current> 
                    </m0:Row> 
                    <m0:Row> 
                        <m0:LimitId>101</m0:LimitId> 
                        <m0:Max>10000</m0:Max> 
                        <m0:Current>0</m0:Current> 
                    </m0:Row> 
                </m0:Limits> 
            </m1:Response>
        </m1:GetLimitsRes>
    </env:Body> 
</env:Envelope>";

            XmlSerializer d = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));
            Envelope e = (Envelope)d.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));

            Console.WriteLine("Iterating all limits:");
            foreach (var lim in e.Body.GetLimitsRes.Response.Limits)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"LimitId: {lim.LimitId}, Current: {lim.Current}, Max: {lim.Max}");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            LimitsRow particularLimit = e.Body.GetLimitsRes.Response.Limits.FirstOrDefault(l => l.LimitId == 101);
            if (particularLimit != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Particular limit: {particularLimit.LimitId}, Current: {particularLimit.Current}, Max: {particularLimit.Max}");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to finish...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }


    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class Envelope
    {

        private EnvelopeBody bodyField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public EnvelopeBody Body
        {
            get
            {
                return this.bodyField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.bodyField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope")]
    public partial class EnvelopeBody
    {

        private GetLimitsRes getLimitsResField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "schemas/app.xsd")]
        public GetLimitsRes GetLimitsRes
        {
            get
            {
                return this.getLimitsResField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.getLimitsResField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "schemas/app.xsd")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "schemas/app.xsd", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class GetLimitsRes
    {

        private GetLimitsResResponse responseField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public GetLimitsResResponse Response
        {
            get
            {
                return this.responseField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.responseField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "schemas/app.xsd")]
    public partial class GetLimitsResResponse
    {

        private LimitsRow[] limitsField;

        private byte responseField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Namespace = "schemas/type.xsd")]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Row", IsNullable = false)]
        public LimitsRow[] Limits
        {
            get
            {
                return this.limitsField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.limitsField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public byte Response
        {
            get
            {
                return this.responseField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.responseField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "schemas/type.xsd")]
    public partial class LimitsRow
    {

        private byte limitIdField;

        private ushort maxField;

        private byte currentField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public byte LimitId
        {
            get
            {
                return this.limitIdField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.limitIdField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public ushort Max
        {
            get
            {
                return this.maxField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.maxField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public byte Current
        {
            get
            {
                return this.currentField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.currentField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "schemas/type.xsd")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "schemas/type.xsd", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class Limits
    {

        private LimitsRow[] rowField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Row")]
        public LimitsRow[] Row
        {
            get
            {
                return this.rowField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.rowField = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michal. It's great for your understand, what I want. Thanks again and wecome to visit my country (Bangladesh, Dhaka) for a dinner (your choice) .

Comment: Michal, your code is ok for simple Deserialize without namespace. If I try to xml:ns, then it was not work.

Comment: Yes Michal, I have not mention it earlier. Can you please give me how I go for it?

Comment: "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
xmlns:m0="http://schemas/type.xsd"
xmlns:m1="http://schemas/app.xsd">
<env:Body>
<m1:GetLimitsRes >
<m1:Response Response="1">
<m0:Limits>
<m0:Row>
<m0:LimitId>100</m0:LimitId>
<m0:Max>10000</m0:Max>
<m0:Current>0</m0:Current>
</m0:Row>
</m0:Limits>
</m1:Response>
</m1:GetLimitsRes>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>"

Answer (score 0):

Try xml Linq anonymous

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;



namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var results = doc.Descendants("Row").Select(x => new {
                limitId = (int)x.Element("LimitId"),
                max = (int)x.Element("Max"),
                current = (int)x.Element("Current")
            }).ToList();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your answer is comply partial. But it is very simple. Thanks.

Comment: Some cases it is easier to manually parse the xml then to deserialize.  I like to give people the choice of which method to use.

Comment: Thanks jdweng. please resolve it: "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <env:Envelope xmlns:env="w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"; xmlns:m0="schemas/type.xsd"; xmlns:m1="schemas/app.xsd">; <env:Body> <m1:GetLimitsRes > <m1:Response Response="1"> <m0:Limits> <m0:Row> <m0:LimitId>100</m0:LimitId> <m0:Max>10000</m0:Max> <m0:Current>0</m0:Current> </m0:Row> </m0:Limits> </m1:Response> </m1:GetLimitsRes> </env:Body> </env:Envelope>"

Comment: There are semicolons in the file that need to be removed.  You can check the xml in cs menu doing following : Project : Add New Item : Xml File.  Then paste xml into view.  Errors will show in the "Error List" like any other compiler error.

Comment: Yes, I have already faced, need replace method to resolve the issue.

Comment: These errors need to be fixed in the code that generated the corrupt xml.  Not edit in your processing code.

Comment: How, please give example.